# Client side error TypeError: a is undefined

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I get data from Webmethod & it need to bind to a table.But my Jquery function not success.Not call webmethod because of Ajax call error.

My Webmethod is

```
 [WebMethod, ScriptMethod]
public static List<UploadedFiles> GetAllUploadedFiles()
{
    List<UploadedFiles> UploadedFilesDetails = new List<UploadedFiles>();
    try
    {
        SqlCommand comGetAllFiles = new SqlCommand("SP_GetAllUploadedFiles", conDB);
        comGetAllFiles.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         if (conDB.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            conDB.Open();

        SqlDataReader rdr = comGetAllFiles.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(rdr);
        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            UploadedFilesDetails.Add(new UploadedFiles
            {
                Id = (int)r["Id"],
                UserId =(Guid)r["UserId"],
                FilePath = r["FilePath"].ToString(),
                Date =(DateTime) r["Date"]

            });
        }

    }
    catch(Exception ee)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        conDB.Close();
    }
    return UploadedFilesDetails;
```

My Ajax Function

```
 <script>
     $(function () {
         LoadUploadFiles();
     });

     function LoadUploadFiles() {

        var url = '<%=ResolveUrl("WebMethods.aspx/GetAllUploadedFiles") %>';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (Result) {
                alert("x");//<-- This alert firing
                $.each(Result.d, function (key, value) {
                    alert(Result.d); //<-- Thisone not firing
                    $("#uploaddata").append($("<table><tr></tr></table>").val
                     (value.Id).html(value.FilePath));

                });
            },
            error: function (e, x) {
                alert(x.ResponseText);
            }
        });
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: add data:""  to $.ajax

Comment: @RaminAsadi Not success

Comment: you can use browser inspect element(chrome) and network tab to know error type

Comment: @RaminAsadi Yes i use firebug.firebug shows me the above error

Comment: Do `console.log(Result)` after `alert('x')` and make sure it looks right.

Comment: @JasonP then it shows tis > Object { Message="Authentication failed.", ExceptionType="System.InvalidOperationException", StackTrace=null}

Comment: Debug your server-side code to figure out where that exception is coming from.

Comment: Unable to debug serverside code because Breakpoint not hit

Comment: use the var url = "WebMethods.aspx/GetAllUploadedFiles";

Comment: So..how can i access it ?Using debugger ? or?? pls explain